# Saving ViewState and ControlState to Session in ASP.Net for a customer facing site

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewstate

I am thinking of using the following code to save all viewstate and controlstate to session for  ASP.Net pages in a website that uses **'in process' sticky sessions** with 30 minutes as session timeout.

On the surface, this appears a very good option to optimize page load times in user's browser.

**Is there any catch/drawback that I may be missing in following this path for a customer facing ASP.Net website?**

```
 protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
    get
    {
        return new SessionPageStatePersister(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a security standpoint, `Session` hijacking should be a concern, especially if there is anything even remotely sensitive stored in the session; this can be mitigated by using SSL to encrypt the delivery of `Session` data including the `SessionID` itself.

From a memory standpoint, the more stuff you put into memory, the less there is of it to go around for everything else. Is 30 minutes too long of a timeout, maybe or maybe not? How many concurrent users does the system have? Will that grow substantially and, if so, when?

Comment: Karl - Is memory the main concern, since security concerns are there with hidden field viewstate also? I don't know the user load, but my guess is about 500 or so at peak hours. There is always a scope of more users coming but nothing planned.

Comment: I would recommend SSL, but if you feel that the `Session` content is not sensitive enough for that, then yes memory would be my main concern beyond that. The good news is you can adjust the length of timeout if memory does become an issue or upgrade the hardware (RAM).